# Can't load sharedpreferences in flutter

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

So I was trying to make a guest mode and user mode, where if the token is null, it will return the guest mode page and vice versa.

The problem is that my token is always null that makes it ends up in the guest mode instead of user mode.

The token is null because when I try to debug, the program skipped the `token = prefs.getString(_sessionTokenKey);`
I have checked the `_sessionTokenKey` storage and there is a token.

```dart
static void loadToken() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    token = prefs.getString(_sessionTokenKey);
}

static Widget _homeBuilder(BuildContext context) {
    loadToken();
    print("this is token from route generator");
    print(token);
    if (token == null) {
        return BottomNavBarGuestMode();
    } else {
        return BottomNavBar();
    }
}

static Route<dynamic> generate(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case Routes.main:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: _homeBuilder, settings: settings);
      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => RouteErrorPage());
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `loadToken` is async. So token is null because you do not wait for an answer of `loadToken`.

Solution:

Add an `await` before your your `laodToaken()` call.

Comment: where do i need to put it?

Comment: change "loadToken();" to "await loadToken();"

Comment: do i need to add async at the _homebuilder?

Comment: It doesn't work the builder on the route method can't accept the _homebuilder method

Comment: Well, then you will have to handle the async of SharedPreferences in another way. I will try to update my answer. Where are you doing the actual navigation call?

Answer (score 0):

You are not following the correct approach to use shared preferences.
Just make a class with your appname and add a static instance for shared preference like this:

```
class AppName{
static SharedPreferences prefs;
}
```

now in you main method initialise the prefs, also make your main function as async as follows:

```
Future<void> main() async {
AppName.prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
}
```

Since you have the preferences initiated now, you can use it easily.So now change your loadToken method as follows:

```
String loadToken(){
    final prefs = AppName.prefs;
    token = prefs.getString(_sessionTokenKey);
    return token;
}
```

And change your _homeBuilder  code as below:

```
static Widget _homeBuilder(BuildContext context) {
    token = loadToken();
    print("this is token from route generator");
    print(token);
    if (token == null) {
        return BottomNavBarGuestMode();
    } else {
        return BottomNavBar();
    }
}
```

You might require to import the AppName class wherever required.

Comment: I have tried this, but the result the prefs is null

Comment: @Vince Since the token variable scope is not clear, so for that i have updated the answer. Now it should work

Comment: The AppName.prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance(); 
the prefs doesn't get the instance

Comment: @Vince did you make the main function async?

Comment: I did, and it doesn't get the instance

Comment: I got the solution, i need to use futurebuilder man haaha

Answer (score 0):

I found that I need to use FutureBuilder(), So that the load data method can run synchronously